# THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture in a loop not working?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've used code from three.js examples, and this  works just fine in another location without being in a loop.

There must be something I'm missing. this is my third rendition of code, and I still cant get it to work.
It seems like the callback is firing too soon or something, because the object appears to be empty.

The error I'm currently getting is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined"... of course.

```
var images = 
[ '01.jpg',
  '02.jpg',
  '03.jpg',
  '04.jpg',
  '05.jpg'  ];

function loadImages(){

 var callbackPainting = function(i) {

    var texture = texturePainting[i];
    console.log(texture); // this returns "undefined"
    var image = texture.image;

    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 100, 100 );
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materialPainting[i] );

    addPainting( scene, mesh );

    function addPainting( zscene, zmesh ) {

      zmesh.scale.x = image.width / 100;
      zmesh.scale.y = image.height / 100;
      // I know this makes the images in the same location. Overlook
      zmesh.position.set(0,0,0);
      zscene.add( zmesh );

    }


  };
  var texturePainting = {}
  var materialPainting = {}
  for(i in images){
    image = "images/" + images[i];
    texturePainting[i] = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( image, THREE.UVMapping, callbackPainting(i) );
    texturePainting[i].minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    materialPainting[i] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texturePainting[i] } );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `texturePainting[i] = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( image, THREE.UVMapping, callbackPainting(i) );` immediately calls `callbackPainting()` with argument `i`.

Rewrite `callbackPainting()` to return a function (and therefore keep each passed value of `i` in a closure), like:

```
var callbackPainting = function(i) {

  return function() {

    var texture = texturePainting[i];
    ...

  }

};
```